# Who is responsible for rendering views in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm a beginner in MVC and i would like to know who is responsible to inject the model data to the view and render it.

Let's analyze this scenario:

- I have a controller that calls a model with it specific method which fetches data from a
  database.
- Then i have a view that renders those data to the user.

Now, after the controller calls the model, who is really responsible for calling the view?

The controller after the model has returned the data? 
Or the model after the data fetch process?

From what i learned about MVC, if i didn't misunderstood, it should be the controller? Right?

I just want a reassurance that i'm thinking right or not...

Thanks to anyone will decide to spend some time on this. I really appreciate it

Comment: A good read for you [MVC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm)

Comment: Thanks!! I will read it now!

Comment: I highly recommend this [reading](https://r.je/views-are-not-templates.html). Good thing about it -- it gives explanations why things are supposed to be one way and not the other.

Comment: @Caius Mark my comment as useful as you finish reading the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will be brief. You're thinking right. Couple days ago I've read and dialogue way to describe this. It's something like this:

- user requests some page
- The request is handeled by app core which talks to controller
- Core: "Hey controller, we've got some request for showing article #1 here"
- Controller: "Got it. Model, you there? Need to get article with id 1 from db, is it fine to you?"
- Model: "Here you go controller, glad you asked."
- Controller: "Thanks model. View, buddy. Please render me an article template with this data (passes data from model)

So as you can see. The model has no clue there is someone called View so neither View does.

Comment: I think this is the most funny and self explainatory answer i could get. Now you've gave me the right requests flow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The controller is indeed responsible for fetching data from a model and then displaying it in a view.

Comment: Thank you! I was supposing that it was the right approach. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: If you’re going to down-vote my answer, a reason as to why would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't seriously. I don't know why all the answers are down voted D:

Comment: @Caius The comment wasn’t aimed at you, it was aimed at whoever down-voted :)

Comment: Ah! Okk! Sorry :) I'm still new to the forum and i don't really know how it works yet :)

Comment: The controller is not responsible for data handling. It doesn't even care about the data. The controller is just a boss. It gathers several components (one or more models, maybe a view, maybe some services), assembles a team and gives it a task to solve. It doesn't tell the components **how** to solve it.

Comment: @axiac I never said it was. A controller gives a view handler some data and says, “View, here’s some data, you do something with it.” That view could then be HTML, JSON, XML, CSV, so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Controller is responsible for this. Model is for database interaction(Logic).

Comment: Thanks! After a whole weekend and sleepless nights passed in front of the pc studying MVC i finally understood the logic.

Comment: Hi Caius, vote for me if you like this. I voted for you

Comment: Dunno, all the answers are down-voted, but i don't know why. Even Martin Bean asked the sam question. Probably someone it's getting fun with the down voting? I would like to upvote all but i can't because i have only 10 rep points D:

Comment: Done it. Just earned the privilege to upvote. Fixed everything :)

Comment: your reputation have been increased now by my vote. you can vote now.

Comment: *"Model is for database interaction(Logic)"* -- database and logic are two different things. The model handles the data, logic and rules of the application. The database is just an implementation detail of the persistence layer. The persistence can be done in many different ways (sometimes it is not even needed). However, there is no mention of persistence (in a database or somewhere else) in MVC.